# Test::Builder::Tester any way to ignore test diagnostics on a failed test?

Tags: perl, testing

I have something like this:

```
test_out( 'not ok 1 - file_mtime_age_ok failure' );
file_mtime_age_ok( $mtime_file, 60*9, 'file_mtime_age_ok failure' );
test_test('file_mime_age_ok failure works');
```

and file_mtime_age_ok generates some diagnostics if the test failed. Like:

```
# Filename [mtime_file] mtime [1393641131] is not 540 seconds within current system time [1393641731].
#   Failed test 'file_mtime_age_ok failure'
#   at t/file_mtime.t line 42.
```

I don't want to have to worry about testing the diagnostics. Digging into the the `test_diag` code, i see that what I pass to `test_diag` is eventually metaquoted with `\Q...\E` [here](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Test-Simple-1.001002/lib/Test/Builder/Tester.pm#L486) so no regex will work. Is there a way I can get by without testing the diagnostics with [Test::Builder::Tester](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Test%3a%3aBuilder%3a%3aTester) and still test my test failure? I tried some sneaky stuff like `open(my $oldout, '>&', STDERR)` and then `open(STDERR, '>', '/dev/null')` and then restoring but I couldn't get that working. The STDERR is tie'd in Test::Builder::Tester and I'll be honest, I never use `tie`'s so my working knowledge of them shallow.

Thanks for any insight.

- Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started digging around on the github issues for test-more since someone must have reported an issue like this before and I came across [issue 387](https://github.com/schwern/test-more/issues/387) which is somewhat related, but not exactly. Seems what I probably want to do is use `test_err` to test against the STDERR which seems to be able to accept regex, at least is accepts regex in Test::Simple 0.99 (this was broke in 0.98).

So I ended up having something like this:

```
  test_out( 'not ok 1 - file_mtime_age_ok failure' );
  test_err(qr/\s*#\s*Filename \[$mtime_file\] [^\n]+\n/);
  test_fail(+1);
  file_mtime_age_ok( $mtime_file, 60*9, 'file_mtime_age_ok failure' );
  test_test('file_mime_age_ok failure works');
```

Which works! I'm still thinking `test_diag` should be able to handle regex, but `test_err` will work for now